# Behavior of data with gaps (using NaN) when using roll period and independent series plotting

Tags: dygraphs

I have run into a problem when using the 'rollPeriod' and 'connectSeparatedPoints' options with data that contain NaN values. When no roll period (=1) is specified, the data appears as expected with gaps. However once you increase the roll period to something >1, the gaps are now connected. Is there a way that the roll period can only be applied to contiguous data points?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

dygraphs averages all the non-null, non-NaN points in the rolling window. As you increase the roll period, there will be fewer windows which contain exclusively null or NaN points.

Comment: What type of moving average does dygraphs use?  It appears a simple moving average centered on the current data point is used, since there is no shift in the data when averaging. Is this correct?

Comment: It's a trailing moving average. You'll definitely notice a shift if you increase the rolling period on the weather chart on dygraphs.com, for example.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification. With a trailing average being used I just expected the first _n-1_ data points to disappear when using a roll period of _n_.    However I have another question related to my initial post for which I have created a jsfiddle example. When dealing with an irregular independent time series, extra points are created during averaging when there are missing values in one series but not another. You can see this creates nearly vertical lines when increasing the roll period. Is it possible to compute the averages separately?    http://jsfiddle.net/bvnLfhrm/31/

Comment: no, unfortunately. it shouldn't be too hard to do yourself though outside of dygraphs, though.